# Can't create user site-packages directory for usercustomize.py file

Tags: python, windows, unicode, module, python-unicode

I need to add the win_unicode_console module to my `usercustomize.py` file, as described by the documentation.

I've discovered my user site packages directory with:

```
>>> import site
>>> site.getusersitepackages()
'C:\\Users\\my name\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python35\\site-packages'
```

I haven't been able to get to this directory using any method. I've tried using pushd instead of cd to emulate a network drive, and I've also tried getting there using run. No matter what I do in python, or in cmd terminal. I get the response `The network path was not found`.

Here is an example of one I've tried in cmd:

```
C:\>pushd \\Users\\my name\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python35\\site-packages
The network path was not found.
```

What am I doing wrong, or what could be wrong with the path?

Comment: (1) Don't double the initial backslash in the cmd shell (doubling the other backslashes doesn't matter; they get collapsed) because it denotes a UNC path, i.e. `pushd` interprets `\\Users\my name` as a UNC path, which it tries to map as a drive. (2) The user site-packages directory doesn't exist initially, not until you install a package as `--user`, so you'll have to create that path manually, starting in `%AppData%` (i.e. `C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming`).

Comment: Okay, I've created the path. I went to run, and typed "%AppData%". It took me to AppData and then I created "AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages". I navigated to site-packages, and created the file in spyder "usercustomize.py", within the file I made the code `import win_unicode_console as wn` skipped 1 line, and wrote `wn.enable()`. Then I opened cmd again as admin, and typed `pushd \Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages` it responds with `The system cannot find the path specified`, even though I just created the path.

Comment: Hmm, the code now works for more than 18 pages. It worked with 20, and 30 for the first time. I tried 100, and 50, however, and it drew the same unicode Error.

Comment: That means your customisation didn't work. If `pushd` or `cd` doesn't work, then you've not created the directory properly and will explain why your customisation doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

DOS style backslashes don't need to be escaped within the Windows console (else they may have used forward slashes way back when!).

Follow these steps to manually create `usercustomize.py`:

1. Start->Run:`cmd`
2. Make sure you're on the C: drive

   ```
   c:
   ```
3. Create the directory. `mkdir` creates the missing parents. Obviously, change *"my name"* as appropriate.

   ```
   mkdir C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages
   ```
4. Create usercustomize.py:

   ```
   notepad C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\usercustomize.py
   ```
5. Click "yes" to create your file.
6. Edit as appropriate

**Or use the following script to have Python do it for you:**

```
import site
import os
import os.path
import io

user_site_dir = site.getusersitepackages()
user_customize_filename = os.path.join(user_site_dir, 'usercustomize.py')

win_unicode_console_text = u"""
# win_unicode_console
import win_unicode_console
win_unicode_console.enable()
"""

if os.path.exists(user_site_dir):
    print("User site dir already exists")
else:
    print("Creating site dir")
    os.makedirs(user_site_dir)

if not os.path.exists(user_customize_filename):
    print("Creating {filename}".format(filename=user_customize_filename))
    file_mode = 'w+t'
else:
    print("{filename} already exists".format(filename=user_customize_filename))
    file_mode = 'r+t'

with io.open(user_customize_filename, file_mode) as user_customize_file:
    existing_text = user_customize_file.read()

    if not win_unicode_console_text in existing_text:
        # file pointer should already be at the end of the file after read()
        user_customize_file.write(win_unicode_console_text)
        print("win_unicode_console added to {filename}".format(filename=user_customize_filename))
    else:
        print("win_unicode_console already enabled")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. When I use the mkdir, however, it says that `A subdirectory or file C:\Users\my name already exists, Error occurred while processing: C:\Users\my name.`

Comment: Try putting the directory path in quotes